# Customized style not applied on angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-components

I need some help regarding an upgrade from Angular 7 to Angular 10.

My angular application was working perfectly without any error and the customized global style was applied!

In previous version (7) if as example a component has a style

```
.p-progress-spinner { width: 100px }
```

and the customized global style has

```
.p-progress-spinner { width: 280px }
```

Angular applied 280px to 'p-progress-spinner', but this behavior changed when I have upgraded to Angular 10; it always take the component style value ( 100px ) instead of the global one!

and if i open browser tool to debug the style, i saw that both are present but only the '100px' is applied.

example :

[image: global style not applied]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

change the component encapsulation to none it will work

something like this

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-no-encapsulation',
 template: `
 <h2>None</h2>
 <div class="none-message">No encapsulation</div>
 `,
 styles: ['h2, .none-message { color: red; }'],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Comment: firstly thank you for your answer but it doesn't help because i'm using Primeng and I cannot change them! .